# argument as a synonym for parameter in c, and c++

Tags: c++

why exactly is the term argument used interchangeably with the term parameter in regards to functions or methods? seems ridiculous to me and in fact undermines programming altogether, except for the fact that it works.

Comment: Sorry. Please explain the difference and how we should know when to use which term.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: @samin, I don't think the essence of your question was bad (_"not constructive"_).  It is useful for a new programmer to get clarification on parameter vs arguments proper use.  However, your second sentence destroyed the credibility of your question.  The tone is argumentative and slightly inflammatory.

Comment: seems to me like people enjoy discussing it...for whatever reason...the tone was slightly argumentative...no pun intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the terms interchangeably is incorrect.

An *argument* is a value passed in a function call.

A *parameter* is an object, local to the function, into which the argument value is copied.

For example:

```
void foo(int parameter) {
    /* ... */
}

/* ... */

int argument = 42;
foo(argument);
```

The definitive reference for this is the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (3.7M PDF).  The words *argument* and *parameter* are defined in 3.3 and 3.15, respectively.

Comment: Ref. [Parameter (Computer Science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_%28computer_science%29): These two terms are sometimes loosely used interchangeably; in particular, "argument" is sometimes used in place of "parameter". Nevertheless, there is a difference. Properly, parameters appear in procedure definitions; arguments appear in procedure calls.

Comment: @Keith: close, but a function defined in C99 or C++ as `void foo(int) { }` still has one parameter, even though there is no object local to the function into which the argument is copied. Parameters are the formally-specified entities for which argument values are assigned -- whether there's a function-local object containing the value is irrelevant.

Comment: @Steve: In C++, yes, but in C that's invalid; you can omit a parameter name in a function declaration, but not in a definition.

Comment: Sorry, don't know why I wrongly imagined C99 had introduced that too. C++ has a similar definition of parameter ("an object or reference declared as part of a function declaration or definition"), maybe I'm stretching a point too far to say that it isn't "local to the function", as you describe it, when it isn't accessible to the function.

Answer (score 2):

To quote Andrei Alexandrescu's book 'The D Programming Language'

> This book consistently uses *parameter* to refer to value accepted and
>   used inside the function and *argument* when talking about the value
>   passed from the outside to the function during invocation.

You are correct that the terms are often used interchangeably.  However, there is clear preference among more seasoned programmers to use them as Andrei describes.